# Dispatch on select element without eval or copy & paste

Tags: javascript, html, dry

edit: This question is a duplicate of "how do I call a javascript function when all I have is a string containing its name". The dom interaction was a distraction.

I would like to call one of N distinct javascript functions when the user chooses an option from a html select element. I'd like to do this without repeating myself or regressing to eval().

Revision one stored strings in the option's value field, then used these as indexes into a dictionary.

```
<body>
<select onchange="dispatch(this)">
<option value="first_function_name">One</option>
<option value="second_function_name">Two</option>
</select>
</body>

<script>
function first_function() {console.log("There can be only one");}
function second_function() {console.log("Except when there are two");}
function dispatch(selection) {
  var name = selection.value;
  var lookup_table = {
    first_function_name: first_function,
    second_function_name: second_function
  };
  (lookup_table[name])();
}
</script>
```

Revision two stores the functions in the value field and calls eval on it. Eval strikes me as absurdly heavy handed.

```
<body>
<select onchange="dispatch(this)"> <!-- Not sure passing this is always OK -->
<option value="first_function()">One</option>
<option value="second_function()">Two</option>
</select>
</body>

<script>
function first_function() {console.log("There can be only one");}
function second_function() {console.log("Except when there are two");}
function dispatch(selection) {eval(selection.value);} /* yuck */
</script>
```

Option three is to aim a code generator at the problem, but that seems defeatist. What is the sane, idiomatic solution to this?

Comment: `(ClosureObject[selection.value])(); // ClosureObject could be Global or Root scope` or simply this depending on where the function is defined

Comment: @vinayakj Thank you for the immediate reply. I can't quite join up the dots though -  how does ClosureObject differ from "revision one"?

Comment: you no need to create a `lookup table` object

Comment: Simply run this in console. `function a(){alert()}
this["a"]()` you would get idea as you already kinda doing it but with some extra code

Comment: @vinayakj Good suggestion. That's quite surprising behaviour - my mental model of javascript is clearly a bit off! Would you mind adding an answer to that effect?

Comment: added the answer with scoped variable, but ofcourse you can also use `Global` scope and can directly use `this['functionName']` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var closureObject = (function(){    // created scope
    /* so now "this" becomes the closureObject and which has all functions as property and
       can directly refer them by syntax Instance['propertyName'] */
    var closureObject = {};
    closureObject.first_function = function() {
          alert("There can be only one");
    }
    closureObject.second_function = function(){
          alert("Except when there are two");
    }
    return closureObject;
    })();

function dispatch(selection) {
          closureObject[selection](); // ClosureObject could be Global or scoped variable
}
```

```html
<select onchange="dispatch(this.value)">
<option value="first_function">One</option>
<option value="second_function">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example (might have to adapt it for different browsers):

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

        var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var options = [ { name: 'One', value:'one', callback: function() {console.log("There can be only one");}},
                        { name: 'Two', value:'two', callback: function() {console.log("Except when there are two");}}];
        options.forEach(
                    function(opt) {
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = opt.name;
                        option.value = opt.value;
                        select.add(option);
                    });
        function onChange() {
            options.some(function(option) {
                if (option.value===select.value) {
                    option.callback();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        select.addEventListener("change", onChange);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the approach of populating both the dom and the callback function from a single dictionary. It's hard to top the elegance of vinayakj's observation though!